# How to compare between parent and children table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: crawl_post, crawl_image and crawl_video.

`CREATE TABLE crawl_post (
    Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ImageCount int,
    VideoCount int
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE crawl_image (
    Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Status bool
    PostId int
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE crawl_video (
    Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Status bool
    PostId int
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);`

`Status = true - downloaded, false - not`

With a query I want to selected all posts that their images and videos are downloaded? That means, count(downloaded image) = post.Imagecount and count(downloaded video) = post.VideoCount.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use join statement? post id is not in crawl_image and crawl_video table?

Comment: Is it necessary for all of those `Id` is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to implement this with the `join` clause, as below:

```
select
    c1.*
from
    crawl_post c1
join
    crawl_image c2 on c1.id = c2.postid and c2.status = 1
join
    crawl_video c3 on c1.id = c3.postid and c3.status = 1
```

the SQL above would return the result of all posts which their image and video is downloaded.

OK, I tried to understand what you want, you just want to get the posts which have finished all the images and the videos download operation both, am I right? I reEdit as below:

```
select cp.* from (
select
    c1.id,
    count(c2.postid) as imageFinishedCount
    count(c3.postid) as videoFinishedCount
from
    crawl_post c1
left join
    crawl_image c2 on c1.id = c2.postid and c2.status = 1
left join
    crawl_video c3 on c1.id = c3.postid and c3.status = 1
group by
    c1.id
) tmp 
join 
    crawl_post cp on tmp.id = cp.id 
where 
    tmp.imageFinishedCount = cp.imageCount and tmp.videoFinishedCount = cp.videoCount
```

Comment: Incorrect, because must be checked count(downloaded image) = post.ImageCount and count(downloaded video) = post.VideoCount

Comment: OK, I have reEdited my answer.

Comment: Just hope it helps.

Comment: Well, we can optimize our SQL according to the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the post by applying the inner join and put the condition for downloaded videos and images as status =1 .

```
Select * from crawl_post cp, crawl_image ci, crawl_video cv 
where cp.id = ci.postid and ci.status = 1 
and cp.id = cv.postid and cv.status =1
```

Comment: should use post.ImageCount and post.VideoCount

Comment: No need to check post.ImageCount, cp.id = ci.postid signify that image refers to that post only

Comment: Yes post to image have many to many relationship right. In that case the join ```cp.id = ci.postid``` will give all the images for that particular post and after since you have put up the condition for downloaded one with ```ci.status = 1 ``` it will give all the images for that post which has been downloaded

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query will help you achieve your goal.

```
  Select * from crawl_post 
              left join crawl_image on crawl_post.Id=crawl_image.PostId
              left join crawl_video on crawl_post.Id=crawl_video.PostId
    where crawl_image.Status=true OR crawl_video.Status=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Query should be as

```
Select crawl_post.Id,
count(distinct crawl_image.Id) as 'downloaded image',
count(distinct crawl_video.Id) as 'downloaded video'
from crawl_post 
join crawl_image on crawl_post.Id=crawl_image.PostId
join crawl_video on crawl_post.Id=crawl_video.PostId
where crawl_image.Status = 1 and crawl_video.Status=1
group by crawl_post.Id;
```